# React: Hide extra elements after 3 elements per section

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

React: I have a menu and list of sub menus. I want to calculate the sub menus count and if it exceed from 3, rest sub menus will be hide.

`Code for try count the elements`

```
export default function App() {
  const ElementRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
      const Elementcount = ElementRef.current.childNodes.length;
      console.log(Elementcount);
  })

  return (   
    <div className="menus" ref={ElementRef}>
     <div className="submenus">
       <div>Menu 1</div>
       <div>Menu 2</div>
       <div>Menu 3</div>

       // Menu 4 & 5 hide
       <div>Menu 4</div>
       <div>Menu 5</div>
      </div>

      <div className="submenus">
        <div>Menu 1</div>
        <div>Menu 2</div>
        <div>Menu 3</div>

        // Menu 4 hide
        <div>Menu 4</div>
       </div>
     </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Answer (score 1):

why not with CSS ? There should be a better one, but this works

```css
.submenus > div{
 display: none  /* hide all */
}

.submenus > div:nth-child(-n+3) {
  display: block   /* show first three */
}
```

```html
<div className="menus">
  <div class="submenus">
    <div>Menu 1</div>
    <div>Menu 2</div>
    <div>Menu 3</div>
    <div>Menu 4</div>
    <div>Menu 5</div>
  </div>

  <hr/>
  <div class="submenus">
    <div>Menu 1</div>
    <div>Menu 2</div>
    <div>Menu 3</div>
    <div>Menu 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const menus = [{name: "menu1"}, {name: "menu2"}, {name: "menu3"}, {name: "menu4"}]

{menus.map((menu, index) => index < 3 ? <div>{menu.name}</div> : null)}
```

Comment: Thanks. This can be some how helpful.

Comment: how I can connect you ? any contact !!